# regular expression: how to capture this group?

Tags: regex

a sample of my text is:

```
per se: of itself. 
ovo: from the beginning. 
abattoir: a slaught: erhouse.
```

the capture group structure is:

[image]

**group 1:** from the beginning of the line till first `:`

**group 2:** `:` (colon+1space) right after end of group 1

**group 3:** right after end of group 2 till end of the line

my pattern is:

```
(^\w+)(: )(.+$)
```

everything with this pattern is ok except this fact that it fails to match first line of the sample text(`per se: of itself.` )

**any idea for modification of the pattern (or maybe a new pattern) so that it matches all of the lines?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
^([^:]+)(: )(.+$)
```

i.e. match everything that isn't a colon (per your spec).